# In Xcode playground, control the string representation in the right side column?

Tags: swift, xcode6, swift-playground, xcode6.3

I thought the `Printable` protocol would do it, but it doesn't. Is there another protocol? I want it to show the 3 numbers, not "C._GLKVector3"

[image]

Comment: There's a `DebugPrintable` protocol.  Perhaps try that?

Comment: I just tried. That's not it.

Comment: Your right.  I just tried it as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of Swift 2 this can be done by making the type conform to `CustomStringConvertible` (previously `Printable`). In the case of `GLKVector3` you would do:

```
extension GLKVector3: CustomStringConvertible {
    public var description: String {
        return "<\(x), \(y), \(z)>"
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try import XCPlayground there is something for that.
Here is everything from that modul: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Swift/Reference/Playground_Ref/Chapters/XCPlayground.html